# Установить дату в DatePicker, но не текущую, а в виде milliseconds из БД

Tags: android, datepicker, calendar

Есть активити для редактирования записей, из БД загружаются ранее сохраненные данные в том числе в textview календаря в виде milliseconds. Эта дата корректно отображается в textview, но при сохранении Calendar сохраняет не ранее загруженную дату из БД, а текущую на устройстве. Если открыть календарь, то в диалоговом окне будет выбрана тоже текущая дата, а не загруженная из БД.

```
    private static String getDate(long millisFromDB, String dateFormat) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(millisFromDB);
    return simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
}

private void setInitialDate() {
    textViewCalendar.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR));
}

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        setInitialDate();
    }
};

public void changeDate(View view) {
    new DatePickerDialog(this, date, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
}
```

Как установить в DatePicker дату из БД в виде milliseconds?

Извините, если такой вопрос уже был, но 3й день поисков ни к чему не привёл. Спасибо.

[image: Выбранная текущая дата (7 февраля), а не загруженная из БД (3 февраля)]

Comment: Вы пробовали вместо year приходящего в параметрах onDateSet(...) использовать calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)?

Comment: Где показ диалога? Нужно перед ним инициализировать. Не нужно инициализировать дважды: в конструкторе и в слушателе.

Comment: Лично я ничего не понял что вам надо (попробуйте перефразировать), кто и как дергает метод getDate(). Метод getData() явно зашкварный. Зачем туда передавать dateFormat если вы его не используете? Покажите весь код в Активити с комментариями  кто что делает, а не 3 метода. Похоже ошибка именно с в другом месте

Comment: Eugene Zaychenko, попробую перефразировать. При открытии диалогового окна календаря, в нём выбрана дата, которая есть текущая на устройстве. Мне нужно чтобы выбранная дата была не текущая на устройстве, а загруженная из БД. Это надо для того, чтобы вот этот код
long dateInSeconds = calendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_DATE, dateInSeconds);
сохранял в БД не текущую дату.

Метод getDate() мне нужен для того чтобы отобразить дату из БД в текствью, делаю я это вот так:
textViewCalendar.setText(getDate((cursorId.getLong(1) * 1000), "dd MMMM yyyy"));

Comment: Style-7, вот вызов диалога, если я Вас правильно понял:
public void changeDate(View view) {
    new DatePickerDialog(this, date, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
}

Comment: Alex_Skvortsov, попробовал. Так невозможно установаить выбранную дату, какую дату я бы не выбрал, всё равно календарь возвращает текущую.

Comment: По нажатию на кнопку вы создаёте диалог со значениями из переменной `calendar`, а где и когда этому календарю выставлено время из базы (так как это сделано для локальной переменной в `getDate`)? Это нужно сделать до нажатия на кнопку, либо в самом обработчике.

Comment: woesss, вот для этого мне и не хватает мозгов. Спасибо, появились кое-какие мысли, буду ещё пробовать. Видел варианты, когда устанавливают дату используя переменные int year, month, dayOfMonth, но мне такой вариант не подходит, так как дата у меня в миллисекундах.

Comment: woesss, спасибо, всё получилось. Сейчас выложу решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо, woesss, натолкнул на правильные мысли.
Солюшн ниже.
Нужно было всего-лишь создать второй экземпляр календаря в классе

```
public class ActivityEdit extends AppCompatActivity {

    Calendar calendarFromDB = Calendar.getInstance();
```

При получении даты из БД установить её только что созданому календарю

```
    long currentMillis = cursorId.getLong(1) * 1000;
    calendarFromDB.setTimeInMillis(currentMillis);
```

И в методах с DatePicker использовать этот календарь

```
private void setInitialDate() {
    textViewCalendar.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, calendarFromDB.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR));
}

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        calendarFromDB.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendarFromDB.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendarFromDB.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        setInitialDate();
    }
};

public void changeDate(View view) {
    new DatePickerDialog(this, date, calendarFromDB.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendarFromDB.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendarFromDB.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
}
```

Теперь при открытии календаря DatePicker устанавливает дату из БД, а если не открывать календарь, то сохранится дата так же из БД.

[image: Дата устанавливается из БД]